# Reshaping a material science Dataset (probably using melt() )

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm dealing with a materials science dataset and I'm in the following situation,

I have data organized like this:

```
Chemical_ Formula     Property_name            Property_Scalar

    He                Electrical conduc.          1
    NO_2              Resistance                  50
    CuO3              Hardness
    ...               ...                        ...
    CuO3              Fluorescence                300
    He                Toxicity                    39
    NO2               Hardness                    80
    ...               ...                         ...
```

As you can understand it is really messy because the same chemical formula appears more than once through the entire dataset, but referred to a different property that is considered. My question is, how can I easily maybe split the dataset in smaller ones, fitting every formula with its descriptors in ORDER? ( I used fiction names and values, just to explain my problem.)

I'm on Jupyter Notebook and I'm using Pandas.

I'm editing my question trying to be more clear:

My goal would be to plot some histograms of (for example) n°materials vs conductivity at different temperatures (100K, 200K, 300K). So I need to have both conductivity and temperature for each material to be clearly comparable. For example, I guess that a more convenient thing to obtain would be:

```
Chemical formula     Conductivity      Temperature

      He                 5                  10K
      NO_2               7                  59K
      CuO_3              10                 300K
      ...                ...                ...
      He                 14                 100K
      NO_2               5                  70K
      ...                ...                ...
```

I think that this issue can be related to reshaping the dataset but I should also have each formula to MATCH exactly  the temperature and conductivity. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to plot Conductivity versus Temperature for a given formula, you can simly select the rows that match this condition.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

formula = 'NO_2'
subset = df.loc[df['Chemical_Formula'] == formula].sort_values('Temperature')
x = subset['Temperature'].values
y = subset['Conductivity'].values

plt.plot(x, y)
```

Here, we are defining the formula you want to extract. Then we are selecting only the rows in the DataFrame where the value in the column 'Chemical Formula' matches your specified formula using `df.loc[]`. This returns a new DataFrame that is a subset of your original DataFrame that contains only rows where our condition is satisfied. We sort this subset by 'Temperature' (I assume you want to plot Temperature on the x-axis) and store it as `subset`. We then select the 'Temperature' and 'Conductivity' columns which return `pandas.Series`objects, which we convert to numpy arrays by calling `.values`. We store these in x and y variables and pass them to the matplotlib plot function.

EDIT:

To get from the first DataFrame to the second DataFrame described in your post, you can use the pivot function (assuming your first DataFrame is named df):

```
df = df.pivot(index='Chemical_Formula', columns='Property_name', values='Property_Scalar')
```

Comment: This doesn't help me at all, sir. Unfortunately, I'm NOT in the situation displayed by my second example dataset (that it is actually where I want to get), but in the one explained by the first one, where I don't have a standard 'Temperature' column as well as a 'Conductivity' one.. My question is exactly about HOW to turn my initial Dataset (first example) in something easier to use (second one) and MATCHING temperature and conductivity for EACH material formula.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In that case you will need to pivot your DataFrame. I'll edit my post shorty.

Comment: Thank you sir! @sunnytown . I’ll see what I can figure out and reach back to you asap 

Comment: Should I filter out dataset with properties I'm interesting in? For example I'm interested in 'conductivity' and 'temperature'. The problem in doing that is, if I filter out separately, ending up with two datasets, then I don't have anymore the match between the two formulas.. right? For example, I filter for 'Conductivity' and I read the property scalar value for NO_2. but at that point, how can I KNOW the temperature value for NO_2, and then for any other formua? ;( I don't know if I explained the point clearly..

Comment: The problem I don't understand is the following: In your second example DataFrame (which you want to achieve), you have a clear association of a specific conductivity to a specific temperature for every row. This is somehow information that is not present in your original DataFrame. How would you generate this information from the original data? I don't see how you can match a specific temperature and conductivity given only your first DataFrame.

Comment: I was thinking to recover the information by rematching the same formula for both ‘conductivity’ and ‘temperature’. As you can see on my first sample-dataset,  I have (for example) ‘He’  with ‘electric bla bla’ and again ‘He’ with ‘toxicity’ , so I should find a way, maybe by string comparing (I was thinking) to match the two properties for the same string ‘formula’  in order to end up with something like the example 2. but my coding skills are not enough for sure... hopefully I’ve explained better the problem, thank you very very much for the consideration 

Comment: I don't quite understand. Lets take NO_2. In your second df you matched the conductivity of 7 to a temperatue of 59K and a Conductivity of 14 to a temperature of 70K. How can this matching be done from the originial df (I don't mean code-wise, I mean logic-wise). How is this information encoded in the original df? You wrote something about order being important. Does it have something to do with that? For example, a conductivity value and the next temperature value for NO_2 occurcing in the dataset belong together?